# iOS: Why BOOL property is not getting set? Value of property is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a notification handler method I am setting a BOOL property (isNotificationCarryingObject) like below:

```
-(void)notificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //set flag depending upon if notification carries an object
    //I tried following:

    //1.
   self.isNotificationCarryingObject = notification.object != nil;
   //result: self.isNotificationCarryingObject = nil

   //2.
   self.isNotificationCarryingObject = notification.object != nil ? YES : NO;
   //result: self.isNotificationCarryingObject = nil

  //3.
  self.isNotificationCarryingObject = YES;
  //result: self.isNotificationCarryingObject = YES ?????

}
```

Using 1. and 2. I am not able to set the flag but using 3. it gets set to YES, I don't understand why? According to me all 3 statements should work.

isNotificationCarryingObject property is defined as:

```
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isNotificationCarryingObject;
```

Notification handler is inside presenting view controller. Presented view controller posts notification inside its -viewWillDisappear method which gets received by presenting view controller.

Comment: How are you checking whether it is set or not? I guess the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: `BOOL` and `nil` don't mix, so something is wrong with your diagnosis.

Comment: Also does the notification contain an object?

Comment: notification.object is nil. For diagnosis I am executing following statements at the end of function: if(isNotificationCarryingObject){ NSLog(@"notification is carrying object"); } //this message gets printed for every case.

Comment: So your code works fine! (except you say `nil` when you mean `NO`).

Comment: @devgr, if the `notification.object` is `nil`, the `isNotificationCarryingObject`'s value has to be `FALSE` or `NO`... a `BOOL` (or any primitive) cannot be `nil` in ObjC.

Comment: Better show how do you call `-notificationReceived:`. Maybe you don't pass object at all.

Comment: @holex thats exactly i think. But it is nil, no clue why?

Comment: @devgr, where did you get it is `nil` from?

Comment: @Droppy yes, if i assign YES or NO to property it works fine.

Comment: The object `notification.object` is nil and thus the BOOL becomes NO

Comment: @sumofighter666 the problem is not related to notification object, it is nil always but BOOL property should have value YES or NO not nil.

Comment: @devgr, I ask you again... where did you get it is `nil` from?

Comment: @holex using po, expression commands. Using this code if(isNotificationCarryingObject){ NSLog(@"notification is carrying object"); } //this message gets printed for every case.

Comment: @devgr how are you checking `self.isNotificationCarryingObject` value after assignment?

Comment: @Kreiri if(isNotificationCarryingObject){ NSLog(@"notification is carrying object"); } //this message gets printed for every case.

Comment: ok question is, do you print it in console like `po self.isNotificationCarryingObject`? then console will display `<nil>`. If you print `p self.isNotificationCarryingObject` console will show `NO`. `po` usually is for printing objects - objects are `nil` primitive data types are either NULL, NO or 0

Comment: @sumofighter666 p self.isNotificationCarryingObject prints nil for case 1 and 2. For case 3 it prints YES.

Comment: And what happens if you assign directly NO like `self.isNotificationCarryingObject = NO;` and print it. Does it still display nil?

Comment: @sumofighter666 NO, it prints NO which is expected.

Answer (score 13):

If you have

```
BOOL b = NO;
```

and you break the program after it and do

```
po b
```

you'll get

```
<nil>
```

do

```
p b
```

instead

`po` stands for `print object`, but a bool is not an object, but a primitive type. Those should be printed withe the `p`-command.

The `nil` object has the address `0x0`, that will evaluate to `0` or `NO` as-well.

Comment: form the comments below the question: *@holex using po, expression commands.*

Comment: And later *@sumofighter666 p self.isNotificationCarryingObject prints nil for case 1 and 2. For case 3 it prints YES*

Comment: @vikingosegundo I am also surprised why

Comment: @vikingosegundo It is working correctly when I made isNotificationCarryingObject iVar instead of property. Someone knows, why?

Comment: Everything is fine with iVar but with property it's an issue.

Comment: again: do u use `p` or `po`?

Comment: I used po and expression, expression prints correct value of property but po prints nil. With iVar po prints correct value as well.

Comment: and what stops you from using `p`?

Comment: I will use p from now onwards. I realized that bool as iVar is much reliable. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: ivar or property shouldn't matter. properties are just syntactic sugar around ivars. and properties are preferred when it comes to KVO/KVC. did you understand the difference between `p` and `po`?

Comment: I did understand that I should use p when dealing with primitive data types.

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
if(notification.object)
notificationFlag=YES;
else
notificationFlag=NO;
```

It could also be a concurrency issue from your monatomic attribute.

Comment: I faced this kind of issue with BOOL declared as property but I realized that with iVar it's much more reliable.